# Easypaginate jQuery plugin not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I unfortunately don't have a windows machine so I can't debug this myself at the moment, but it seems as though this plugin http://cssglobe.com/post/9801/easy-paginate-jquery-plugin-for-pagination works perfectly fine in every browser—including IE7,8 but not IE9. Has anyone experienced this or find a proper solution? You can see the results on my site http://www.goodgreenfight.com

Thanks.